# How to delete the "Given" in a coplot using R

Tags: r, graphics, statistics

Is there anybody who knows how to delete the "Given" signatures in a coplot? I know how to use coplot(...,show.given=FALSE),but this deletes more than just the "Given". I hope you guys understand what I'm talking about, because my English isn't that good!

Bye

Answer (score 8):

Here is a reproducible example from `?coplot`:

```
## Tonga Trench Earthquakes
coplot(lat ~ long | depth, data = quakes)
```

The question therefore is how to stop R writing the "Given :" in the label in the shingle part of the plot, or for that matter change the entire label.

If we look at the help for `?coplot`, we see that the arguments for the x- and y-axis labels (`xlab` and `ylab` respectively) take two values, and it is the default behaviour to prepend `"Given : "` to the second element in each label for the conditioning variable.

The solution therefore is to supply your own labels:

```
coplot(lat ~ long | depth, data = quakes, xlab = c("Longitude", "Depth"),
       ylab = "Latitude")
```

which gives:

[image: coplot example]

Comment: Thank you Gavin, that works great! I know it is offtopic, but do you also know how to get rid of the background rectangles?

Comment: @user734124 Do you mean the grids on the individual panels or the grey rectangles in the top Depth panel? You need the latter, and the former are hard coded into the `coplot()` function. You could do `fixInNamespace(coplot, "graphics")` and fin this line `grid(lty = "solid")` and comment it out. Close/save the editor and redo the plot.

Comment: @user734124 If my answer solves the problem, can you check the tick underneath the votes and up/down triangles to the left of the Answer. That way people how find your question know it was Answered?

Comment: Hey Gavin I've deleted that line (I hope you meant delete by fin :D)... But the rectangles are still present :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Commenting the line means just put `#` at the start. Actually, seems you want `fix(coplot)` instead. That works, I just tried it. Run that line, comment out, save/exit the editor and then run `coplot()` again.